# Programming with Python an Industrial pc to -Control Hydraulic Valves

Tags: python, automation, industrial

I have been recently introduced to the Industrial Autmoation programming using Python. For that matter, my employer has purchased a Industrial PC and desired to control the Pressure Valves, Hyfrauliv Valves with the help of Program coded on Python. I am however, not sure how to go about it. Could anyone please guide me ?

Comment: This question needs way more detailed info. How is the Valve connected to the PC for starters maybe?

Comment: PRofiBus is the channel between valves and the PC.

Comment: pip install pyprofibus and take a look at the examples that come with it

Comment: okay noah. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Can i personally reach you for any further query ?